# Is there a way to forcefully compile or render component using text inside interpolation handlebars

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using some third party Vue component which allow me to set the title of a group of Html element and the text is rendered inside legend tag.

From what I understand, Vue interpolation text can do only handful of operation.

And I am wondering if there is a way for me to render the vue custom component inside the vue interpolation handlebar.

E.g. Inside the template of my vue component ...

```
<template>

  <div class="row">
     <legend>{{ Text_Or_CustomVueComponentTag }} </legend>
     ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there any hack I can do to render my own custom **component** inside handlebar ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think it is a wrong way (primarily option-based). And the sample you posted out is use **Mustache**, it will replace the value property of one dom element.

As the [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) said:

> The mustache tag will be replaced with the value of the msg property
> on the corresponding data object. It will also be updated whenever the
> data object’s msg property changes.

Though we can update innerHTML directly by `v-html` directive. But I don't think you will get any benefit, if uses `v-html`, why not directly uses your child component.

```js
Vue.component('child', {

  template: '<div><span style="background-color:green">{{ updatedArray }}</span><div style="background-color:red">{{computedArray}}</div></div>',
  props: ['updatedArray'],
  computed: {
    computedArray() {
      if(this.updatedArray.item.length > 0) {return this.updatedArray}
      else {return "other item"}
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testArray: {
        'item': 'test',
        'prop1': 'a'
      },
      childComponent1: '<div>Nothing</div>',
      childComponent2: '<div>Nothing</div>'
    }
  },
  methods:{
    resetArray: function() {
      this.testArray['item'] += this.testArray['prop1'] + 'b'
      this.childComponent1 = this.$refs.test.$el.innerHTML
      setTimeout(()=>{this.childComponent2 = this.$refs.test.$el.innerHTML}, 0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="resetArray()">Click me</button>
<child ref="test" v-bind:updated-array="testArray"></child>
<div v-html="childComponent1"></div>
<div v-html="childComponent2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can only pass the text as a property of a component and that components use the value I set in prop and it render it using vuejs  interpolation (using mustache like handlebar) in Vue component that I am using. So I have no control on changing anything except I can only pass in some value to prop of a component that gets rendered inside '{{ myValue }}'